# How to use hard-coded keys for two parties to form key agreement using ECDH from cryptopp library as demonstration?

Tags: c++, cryptography, crypto++, cryptoapi

I need your help through This code that is an example of how to use the Crypto++ library to perform a Diffie-Hellman key exchange. The code uses the secp256r1 curve to generate the public and private keys and then uses the ECDH class to perform the key agreement. The code takes in two input strings, one for the private key of the first party (A) and one for the public key of the second party (B). It then converts these strings from hexadecimal to bytes and assigns them to SecByteBlock variables. It then uses the "Agree" method of the ECDH class to compute the shared secret between the two parties and stores it in a "sharedA" variable. Finally, the code converts the shared secret to an Integer and displays it in hexadecimal format., how it can be corrected to produce correct “Agreed shared secret key” which is supposed to be `"1ed885b1064ae5e041cef89365eb7a63b87a6e3e59f6b3ec74c117b74c4e89a4"`

The code;

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cerr;
using std::endl;

#include <string>
using std::string;

#include <stdexcept>
using std::runtime_error;

#include <cstdlib>
using std::exit;

#include "cryptopp/osrng.h"
using CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool;
using CryptoPP::AutoSeededX917RNG;

#include "cryptopp/aes.h"
using CryptoPP::AES;

#include "cryptopp/eccrypto.h"
using CryptoPP::ECP;
using CryptoPP::ECDH;

#include "cryptopp/secblock.h"
using CryptoPP::SecByteBlock;

#include "cryptopp/oids.h"
using CryptoPP::OID;

// ASN1 is a namespace, not an object
#include "cryptopp/asn.h"
using namespace CryptoPP::ASN1;

#include "cryptopp/integer.h"
using CryptoPP::Integer;

#include <cryptopp/hex.h>

int main( int, char** ) {

    OID CURVE = secp256r1();

    ECDH < ECP >::Domain dhA( CURVE ), dhB( CURVE );
    
    string privatekeyA = "e8586d5fa27ffb6a37817c171c94189ad20d8fcf29fa58ba0e6cbe4cf2bb1079";
    string publickeyB = "4f0609f35a0be01caa1287862680b803ea50fb66af2ad65e990aa4a8944c6191ac0d13d98612e12ba1d9afa86f997aab2827a0cee43bf963e8e995eb95df2fb33";

    SecByteBlock privA(dhA.PrivateKeyLength());
    SecByteBlock pubB(dhB.PublicKeyLength());  
    
    string Prkey, Pukey;
    unsigned char privateky[32];
    unsigned char publicky[64];

    CryptoPP::StringSource ssk(privatekeyA, true ,
        new CryptoPP::HexDecoder(
            new CryptoPP::StringSink(Prkey)
        )
    );

    CryptoPP::StringSource ssv(publickeyB, true ,
        new CryptoPP::HexDecoder(
            new CryptoPP::StringSink(Pukey)
        )
    );

    for(int i=0;i<32;i++) {
            if (Prkey[i]<0) privateky[i]=Prkey[i]+256;
            else privateky[i]=Prkey[i];
        } 

    for(int i=0;i<64;i++) {
            if (Pukey[i]<0) publicky[i]=Pukey[i]+256;
            else publicky[i]=Pukey[i];
        } 
        
    privA.Assign(privateky, sizeof(privateky));
    pubB.Assign(publicky, sizeof(publicky));

    SecByteBlock sharedA(dhA.AgreedValueLength());

    dhA.Agree(sharedA, privA, pubB);

    Integer a;

    a.Decode(sharedA.BytePtr(), sharedA.SizeInBytes());
    cout << "Agreed to shared secret: " << std::hex << a << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this code is wrong. so help.

when i run the code above the output is this;
`Agreed to shared secret: 8038e60132560000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000h`

instead of this;
 `"1ed885b1064ae5e041cef89365eb7a63b87a6e3e59f6b3ec74c117b74c4e89a4"`

Comment: As public key the *uncompressed* key is to be taken, which starts with a leading 0x04. For secp256r1 it is 65 bytes in size. Therefore a leading 0 must be added to `publickeyB` (so that the key has 130 hexdigits). Furthermore, the size of the array and the upper limit of the loop variable regarding `publicky` must be increased to 65. Then the expected shared secret is generated.

Comment: Note that the fix for `publicky` is actually not necessary, since `privateky` and `publicky` are not needed at all. Instead, `Prkey` and `Pukey` can be used *directly* in `Assign()` (data and size can be retrieved via the corresponding `std::string` methods).